# How to handle the case when input to reduce is hash rather than array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have an incoming input which is sometimes an array of hashes and sometimes its just an individual hash.

```
hsh = {"property"=>[{"name"=>"first_name", "value"=>"Joe"}, {"name"=>"last_name", "value"=>"Doe"}]}
```

or

```
hsh = {"property"=>{"name"=>"Foo", "value"=>"Bar"}}
```

From this input I am trying to generate a hash with `name` as `key` and `value` and as `value`, something like this:

```
hsh['property'].reduce(HashWithIndifferentAccess.new) do |scan, kv_pair|
  scan.merge kv_pair['name'] => kv_pair['value']
end
```

Giving:

```
{"first_name"=>"Joe", "last_name"=>"Doe"}
```

This works well when `hsh['property']` is an array of hashes but fails with the following error:

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
```

when it's just an hash.

How do I handle the `reduce` on `hsh['property']` so it handles the case when input to it is hash rather than array of hashes?

Comment: Probably just check the type. I.e. `if value.is_a?(Hash) ... else `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd convert the incoming parameter to an array of a single hash, then proceed:

```
def foo(aoh)
  aoh = [aoh] unless Array === aoh

  aoh # return it so we can see it's been changed

  # do stuff with the AoH
end

foo({a:1}) # => [{:a=>1}]
foo([{a:1},{b:2}]) # => [{:a=>1}, {:b=>2}]
```

Once it's an array of a single hash, or multiple hashes, you can iterate over the contents of the array with the same code.

If you are responsible for generating the single hash or an array of hashes, you should always generate the same type of object, an array of hashes, which makes it easier for you to deal with it. If you don't, then convert it to the same type of object and move on.

Comment: I am partially responsible, meaning I am using `httparty` gem to hit an API endpoint which return an XML. The httparty response object's parsed_response is the one which is forming this hash.

Comment: Then immediately change the returned value so you have a consistent result. Don't live with the misery of having to jump one way or other because the data type changes.

Answer (score 4):

It's easy to ensure something being an array. You don't need if-else. Just wrap it in a new array, then flatten that array 1 level down. I have to admit that this is not very performant, but I don't care if what I originally want to do is O(n) or higher (like mapping, reducing, sorting, whatever that requires traversing the array at least once). I won't go this way if what I originally want to do is O(log(n)) or lower (like binary search).

```
[hsh['property']].flatten(1).reduce(HashWithIndifferentAccess.new) do |scan, kv_pair|
  scan.merge kv_pair['name'] => kv_pair['value']
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to fix is to get rid of `merge` which creates an intermediate Hash each time through the loop. That's a lot of garbage to collect. The second thing is to use the simpler `each_with_index` method that doesn't require chaining. This way you can just add data:

```
hsh['property'].each_with_object(HashWithIndifferentAccess.new) do |kv_pair, scan|
  scan[kv_pair['name']] = kv_pair['value']
end
```

This will work so long as `property` has a series of Hash objects in an array. If you have just one you'll need to special case that:

```
case hsh['property']
when Hash
  HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(
    hsh['property']['name'] => hsh['property']['value']
  )
when Array
  hsh['property'].each_with_object(HashWithIndifferentAccess.new) do |kv_pair, scan|
    scan[kv_pair['name']] = kv_pair['value']
  end
else
  # Uh-oh, you've got to handle this case of something random.
end
```

Comment: The `Array` part 
`properties.each_with_index(HashWithIndifferentAccess.new) do |scan, kv_pair|
          scan[kv_pair['name']] = kv_pair['value']
 end`
errors out with `ArgumentError Exception: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)`. Seems like `each_with_index` doesn't take any argument.

Comment: Will it be `each_with_object` rather than `each_with_index`.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using rails, there is a dedicated method for ensuring something is an array - [`Array#wrap`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/Array.html#method-c-wrap). Also note that your use of `#reduce` is considered unindiomatic and you should use `#each_with_object` instead.

Here is a possible solution:

```
Array.wrap(hsh['property']).map { |kv| [kv['name'], kv['value']] }.to_h
```

---

If you are using ruby 2.3.0+, you can even take advantage of the cool new `Hash#to_proc`:

```
Array.wrap(hsh['property']).map { |kv| ['name', 'value'].map(&kv) }.to_h
```

---

If you insist, you can add the `#with_indifferent_access` at the end.